# Get Time From 5 Minutes Prior

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on User Functions for the CMS I'm working on and I have users updated on each page load Using

```
if(User("online") == true) {
    LastOnlineUpdate($_SESSION['key']['userid']);
}
```

(Yes User Online Works, That's my function to check online users)
And now my times are updated correctly hooking into the LastOnlineUpdate function then running my class function

```
    public function SessionUpdate($arg) {
        $query = <<<SQL
        UPDATE {$this->tprefix}online
        SET remote = :remote, timestamp = :timestamp
        WHERE userid = :arg
        SQL;
        $resource = $this->db->db->prepare( $query );
            $resource->execute( array( 
            ':remote'   => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
            ':timestamp'    => time(),
            ':arg'  => $arg,
            ));
    }
```

Now whenever I go through my pages it updates the user by having the first code within my preloaded file, now I've hit my roadblock though with something I've never done and that's to take the time that's been inserted into my table, select it if the time is less than five minutes and utilize it for my online users section

```
public function OnlineUsers() {
       $query = <<<SQL
       SELECT userid
       FROM {$this->tprefix}online
       WHERE timestamp > time(5Minutes)
SQL;
       $resource = $this->db->db->prepare( $query );
       $resource->execute();
       $this->onlinecount = $resource->rowCount();
       if($resource->rowCount() == 0 ) {
            $this->onlineusers = "No User's Online";
       }
       else 
       {
            foreach($resource as $row) {
                self::ConvertIDToName("displayname"); //Can be display, user, first or whatever else for the argument, The onlineusers variable is then set based off that query
            }
       }
}
```

Comment: Whoever edited this post. Just as a heads up, indenting `SQL;` would actually break the code.

Comment: Sorry for that actually I'm not aware of that it's my bad.

Comment: Not a problem, just didn't want someone else to try to learn from it being malformed. :) And it wouldn't let me edit it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$minutes = 5;
$date = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php
$date_plus_minutes = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', ( time() + $minutes * 60 ) );
$date_minus_minutes = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', ( time() - $minutes * 60 ) );
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was after, but I was able to use gmdate rather, change up the code and utilize it to check and it works like a charm. Thanks H3